# How to use a dynamic forms names in a class (C#.Net)

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I had long time developing windows applications using VB.NET and one of thing that I was always use is:

Class (Test) and inside it there are some subs like the following:

**VB.NET Code**

```
 Friend Sub FLoadKeyLock(ByVal FRMNAME As Object)
        FRMNAME.Button3.Enabled = true;
        FRMNAME.Button4.Enabled = true;
        FRMNAME.Button1.Enabled = false;
        FRMNAME.Button2.Enabled = false;
        FRMNAME.Button5.Enabled = false;
        FRMNAME.Button6.Enabled = false;
        FRMNAME.Button7.Enabled = false;
        FRMNAME.Button8.Enabled = false;
        FRMNAME.Button9.Enabled = false;
        FRMNAME.Button10.Enabled = false;
 End Sub
```

Where FRMNAME refers to forms name that I send from different forms and I use (me) keyword to send current form name to apply that sub.

That was totally works fine in VB.NET but I cannot use it the same way in C#.NET.

**C#.NET Code**

```
 internal void FLoadKeyLock (Form FRMNAME)
    {
        FRMNAME.Button3.Enabled = true;
        FRMNAME.Button4.Enabled = true;
        FRMNAME.Button1.Enabled = false;
        FRMNAME.Button2.Enabled = false;
        FRMNAME.Button5.Enabled = false;
        FRMNAME.Button6.Enabled = false;
        FRMNAME.Button7.Enabled = false;
        FRMNAME.Button8.Enabled = false;
        FRMNAME.Button9.Enabled = false;
        FRMNAME.Button10.Enabled = false;
    }
```

**The Error is:** System.Windows.Forms.Form' does not contain a definition for 'Button3' and no extension method 'Button3' accepting a first argument of type

And same error for all used buttons.

**So I have two questions:**

1 - How to use such a function in C#.NET?

2 - Why it's not working the same way as VB.NET?

Comment: If you want to use `dynamic`, change the C# method signature to `internal void FLoadKeyLock (dynamic FRMNAME)`. Obviously you compile-time type-safety.

Comment: Your method has no actual way of "knowing" what buttons are there in your form, unless you pass the actual type of the form (like `MyForm`, instead of the base `Form` class. If it was a `Form`, how can you ensure that your method will not receive a form instance that doesn't actually have any of those buttons?

Comment: That said, I suggest you research about proper design patterns.

Comment: @Maarten Brilliant, Solved my problem (Many thanks to you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Maarten said.
dynamic has solved my problem

```
internal void FLoadKeyLock (dynamic FRMNAME)
{
    FRMNAME.Button3.Enabled = true;
    FRMNAME.Button4.Enabled = true;
    FRMNAME.Button1.Enabled = false;
    FRMNAME.Button2.Enabled = false;
    FRMNAME.Button5.Enabled = false;
    FRMNAME.Button6.Enabled = false;
    FRMNAME.Button7.Enabled = false;
    FRMNAME.Button8.Enabled = false;
    FRMNAME.Button9.Enabled = false;
    FRMNAME.Button10.Enabled = false;
}
```